# -bash: ng: command not found after installing @angular/cli using npm link @angular/cli@latest

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am using:

node -v
v10.15.3

npm -v
6.4.1

I have tried below mentioned command

command: npm i -g angular/cli

> Error while executing: npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t
>   ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git

command: npm i -g @angular/cli

> npm ERR! path /Users/admin/.node_modules/bin/ng npm ERR! code EEXIST
>   npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/admin/.node_modules/bin/ng:
>   ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not
>   controlled by npm
>   /Users/admin/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli npm ERR! File
>   exists: /Users/admin/.node_modules/bin/ng npm ERR! Move it away, and
>   try again.

Comment: you try with admin privilege?

Comment: yes I have tried using sudo also

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct path in Enviroment variable -> user variable like this

[image]

In this case my npm folder are located at

```
C:\Users\phuc.ngo\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

The npm folder is where everything you install can be found like angular cli, webpack, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to try installing angular with admin previledge and try to install it globally with -g

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

after installation check the angular version

`ng --version`